# Laravel Problema com passagem de parâmetros para Controllers

Tags: laravel, controller

então estou com um problema pertinente.
Eu preciso criar um link para o controller.edit para editar claro um valor no banco. 
Ja tentei praticamente de tudo. Mas eu continuo recebendo um erro:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/projeto/resources/views/aluno.blade.php)

Eu estou atualmente usando Forms&HTML do laravel e abri um formulario do apontando pro edit:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['aluno.edit', $aluno->id],'method'=> 'get']) !!}
      {!! Form::submit('Editar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'id'=>'bt'])!!}
      {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Meu controller:

```
public function edit($id){
$aluno = $this->aluno->find($id);
return view('aluno', compact('aluno'));
```

}

Na minha view aluno.blade.php:

```
 @if (isset($aluno))
          {!! Form::model($aluno,['route'=>['aluno.update',$aluno->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal m-t-20','method'=>'PUT']) !!}
        @else
          {!! Form::open(['route'=>['aluno.store'],'method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal m-t-20']) !!}
        @endif
```

Ja tentei passar por link:

```
<a href="{{route('aluno.edit',$aluno->id)}}" class="edit actions "><span></span> </a>
```

Sempre recebo o mesmo erro falando que era esperado uma string e passo um array

Uso o mesmo para o metodo destroy e funciona perfeitamente:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['aluno.destroy', $aluno->id], 'method'=> 'DELETE']) !!}
      {!! Form::submit('Apagar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'id'=>'bt'])!!}
      {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Eu estou fazendo alguns testes, parece que esse erro ta vindo devido aos Forms, eu apontei para outro controller ex:

```
 {!! Form::open(['route'=>['instrutor.edit', $aluno->id],'method'=> 'get']) !!}
      {!! Form::submit('Editar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'id'=>'bt'])!!}
      {!! Form::close() !!}
```

E abriu normalmente então segue minha view aluno

Novo Aluno

```
      <div class="">
        @if (isset($aluno))
          {!! Form::model($aluno,['route'=>['aluno.update',$aluno->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal m-t-20','method'=>'PUT']) !!}
        @else
          {!! Form::open(['route'=>['aluno.store'],'method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal m-t-20']) !!}
        @endif


          @if (isset($errors) && count($errors)>0)
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                      <p> {{$error}} </p>
                  @endforeach
              </div>
          @endif

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('nome', 'Nome', ['class' => 'control-label','for'=>'nome']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('nome',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'nome']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('cpf','CPF',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'cpf']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('cpf',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'cpf']) !!}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('email','Email',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'email']) !!}
            {!! Form::email('email',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'email']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('data_nascimento','Data de Nascimento',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'data_nascimento']) !!}
            {!! Form::date('data_nascimento',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'data_nascimento']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('telefone','Telefone',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'telefone']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('telefone',"",['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'telefone']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('celular','Celular',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'celular']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('celular',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'celular']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('cep','Cep',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'cep']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('cep',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'cep']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('estados','Estado',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'estados']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('estados',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'estados']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('cidade','Cidade',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'cidaade']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('cidade',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'cidade']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('bairro','Bairro',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'bairro']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('bairro',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'bairro']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('rua','Rua',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'rua']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('rua',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'rua']) !!}

            {!! Form::label('numero','Número',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'numero']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('numero',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'numero']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('dataini','Data Matricula',['class'=>'control-label','for'=>'dataini']) !!}
            {!! Form::date('dataini',"",['class'=>'form-control','required','id'=>'dataini']) !!}
          </div>

          <div class="form-group text-right m-t-20">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              @if (isset($aluno))
                {!! Form::submit('Editar',['route'=>['aluno.edit',$aluno->id] ,'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'id'=>'btn']) !!}
              @else
                {!! Form::submit('Cadastrar',['route'=>'aluno.store','class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-just-icon', 'id'=>'btn']) !!}
              @endif
                {!! Form::reset('Limpar',['class'=>'btn btn-default btn-just-icon', 'id'=>'bt']) !!}
            </div>
          </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: Você já tentou usar _['route'=>['aluno.edit', $aluno->id], **'method'=> 'PUT'**]_? No seu controller a rota deve aceitar o método PUT também.

Comment: Sim quando eu mudo o Method sem ser pra get recebo esta mensagem:
MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Esse erro deve ser porque no seu controller o método edit está mapeado como GET. você pode mudar para PUT para fazer o teste?

Comment: Olha, eu tenho receio de n ser possível, ou então não faço ideia como faz Meu controller é do tipo resource ele ja vem com esses methods pré estabelecidos

Comment: Como esta seu route?

Comment: Route::resource('/instrutor', 'InstrutorController');
Route::resource('/aluno', 'AlunoController');
Route::resource('/modalidade', 'ModalidadeController');
Route::resource('/aula', 'AulaController');